# Как сохранить результат выбранного селекта в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, css-selectors, if

Есть два селекта:

```
<select id="id1" disabled>
  <option value="0">- текст -</option>
  <option value="1">- текст -</option>
  <option value="2">- текст -</option>
</select>
```

и

```
<select id="id2" disabled>
  <option value="0">- 1 -</option>
  <option value="1">- 2 -</option>
  <option value="2">- 3 -</option>
</select>
```

Я создал массив:

```
var resultId1 = [0, 0, 0];
```

Например, если выбрать в селекте (`id1`) первый вариант (`value = 0`), а затем в селекте (`id2`), например тоже первый вариант (`value = 0`). В массиве 3 ячейки, соответствующие количеству вариантов в селекте (`id2`). Мне нужно как-то записывать сколько раз было выбран тот или иной вариант в селекте (`id2`) в зависимости от выбранного значения селекта (`id1`). В Селекте (`id1`) гораздо больше вариантов будет, а во втором всего три. Я думал сделать через `if else`, но слишком много их будет, не думаю что это правильно. То есть:

```
if (выбрано value = 0 в id1) { 
  if (выбрано value = 0 в id2) { 
      добавить в массив resultId1 в ячейку 0 число 1 
   } else if {...}... }
```

Но такая конструкция слишком большая. Может как-нибудь по-другому можно?

Comment: тоесть вам надо в итоге получить для каждого селекта массив, с количеством по опциях, какую сколько раз было выбрано ?

Comment: Для каждого селекта (id1). С количеством сколько раз было выбрано то или иное в селекте (id2)

Comment: но селект с `id="id1"` только  один...

Comment: ой, для каждого варианта (value) в селекте (id1).

Comment: тоесть надо в для каждого оптион а селекте 1 хранить массив, сколько раз какое значение было выбрано в селекте 2 ?

Comment: Да. Есть кнопка "Сохранить" с функцией save(), где и будет решение этой задачи. Сохранятся будет через LS, чтобы при обновлении страницы результат сколько раз было нажато не стералось.

Comment: при загрузке страницы, в селекте 2 будет активным первое значение, это щитается как выбрано ? его надо в массив добавлять ?

Comment: Нет, это не считается, поскольку сохранение в массив будет происходить только в функции, которая вызывается при нажатии на button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример. Для сохранения выбора жмите выбрать, для того чтобы посмотреть результаты - Вывести лог.

```js
var counter = {};
var options = document.getElementById('id1').options;
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  counter[options[i].value] = [0, 0, 0];
}
document.getElementById("save").onclick = function() {
  var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
  var value1 = id1.options[id1.selectedIndex].value;
  var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");
  var value2 = id2.options[id2.selectedIndex].value;
  counter[value1][value2]++;
};
document.getElementById("log").onclick = function() {
  console.log(counter);
};
```

```html
<select id='id1'>
<option value='0'>Нулевой</option>
<option value='1'>Первый</option>
<option value='2'>Второй</option>
<option value='3'>Третий</option>
<option value='4'>Четвертый</option>

</select>
<select id='id2'>
<option value='0'>Нулевой</option>
<option value='1'>Первый</option>
<option value='2'>Второй</option>
</select>
<button id='save'>Выбрать</button>
<button id='log'>Вывести лог</button>
```

Comment: что-то не очень понял.. а если в первом селекторе выбран не первый вариант, а десятый? То value1 уже не будет === value2.

Comment: Если в первом будет десятый, а во втором первый, то не равно конечно. Возможно я не совсем понял что требуется, добавьте в вопрос более сложный пример.

Comment: по сути, мне нужно для каждого варианта в селлекторе (id1) массив, в который будет записываться количество раз нажатия того или иного варианта в селлекторе (id2). Естественно не суммарное нажатие на селлектор (id2), а первый вариант в одну ячейку, второй вариант в другую ячейку, третий вариант в третью ячейку массива. Так стало яснее?)

Comment: Внес изменения, попробуйте.

Comment: Все работает. Только пару моментов. В реальности у меня во втором селекторе первый вариант не выбирается, поэтому начинается отсчет с 1, а не с 0. Как можно отнсять 1 от value1, чтобы к правильному выбору относилось. 

И еще вот что, у меня вместо первого селектора вот такой: https://jsfiddle.net/7crsysmy/14/. Просто он собирается сам с помощью скрипта. И нужно чтобы value первого селектора было что-то вроде: all_leagues1[0][0] в зависимости что выбрано. Это сильно меняет дело?

Comment: `counter[value1-1][value2]++` что-то вроде такого просто будет

Comment: только во втором селекторе, пробовал, не получилось. Хотя все заработало, только от value2. А что насчет второго вопроса, не знаете как решить можно?

Comment: Да, там чуток по-другому надо будет, но тоже несложно. По поводу второго - именно через value я бы не делал, но можно же любой кастомный атрибут прикрутить и в него что угодно положить

Comment: Не очень понимаю как переделать под мой селектор. Наверное стоило сразу в задании указать мой селектор, думал что пойму логику и сам переделаю

Answer (score 1):

Если я понял, то что-то такое должно подойти :

```js
var selected = {};
let select1 = document.getElementById('id1');
let select2 = document.getElementById('id2');

[...select1.options].forEach(o => {
  selected[o.value] = [0, 0, 0];
});
select2.addEventListener('change', function() {
  selected[select1.value][this.value] += 1;
});

function func() {
  document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = '';
  Object.keys(selected).forEach(k => {
    document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML += `${k} = ${selected[k]}<br/>`;
  });
};
```

```html
<select id="id1">
  <option value="0">- текст 1 -</option>
  <option value="1">- текст 2 -</option>
  <option value="2">- текст 3 -</option>
</select>

<select id="id2">
  <option value="0">- 1 -</option>
  <option value="1">- 2 -</option>
  <option value="2">- 3 -</option>
</select>

<button onclick="func();">Show</button>
<hr/>
<div id="res2"></div>
```

Comment: так, а как вывести не в консоль, а на страницу? Например, первую ячейку и вторую? А то document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = selected[0]; не работает

Comment: например так, как я щасс добавил, но это всеголиш дело вкуса )

Comment: как-то странно работает, если менять первый селект не меняя второй, то ничего не происходит.

Comment: а если поменять первый не меняя второй, то значение должно стать `[0,0,0]` ?

Comment: если поменять первый не меняя второй не трогая кнопка сохранения, то ничего не произойдет же. А если уже сохранили, то и значение должно быть изменено. Не очень понял вопрос

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych что за троеточие  скажите пожалуйста [...select1.options] ?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов спред оператор, загуглите и почитайте что это

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych спасибо большое

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych еще один вопрос я бы хотел задать.Погуглил ничего не нашел насчет того options который стоит рядом с оператором spread(...select1)  что он делает  откуда вообще он появился ?Спасибо буду благодарен если ответите

Comment: @Избытоксусликов это специфическое свойство именно элемента `select` - набор его `options`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych спасибо вам большое  еще раз