# Создать массив для выбранного селектора

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть код: https://jsfiddle.net/7crsysmy/15/

И `JS`:

```
var counter = {};
var options = document.getElementById('id1').options;
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  counter[options[i].value] = [0, 0, 0];
}


 var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
 var value1 = id1.options[id1.selectedIndex].value;
 var id2 = document.getElementById("result_id");
 var value2 = id2.options[id2.selectedIndex].value;
 value2 = value2 - 1;
 counter[value1][value2]++;
```

Сейчас `JS` код помещает в массив количество раз нажатия того или иного варианта в селлекторе (`id2`), в зависимости от выбранного варианта в селлекторе (`id1`). Но у меня вместо селектора (`id1`) - селектор, созданный скриптом из массива. У него я так понял нет `value` как у обычного селлектора, а у него `all_leagues1[0][0]`, где первая цифра - выбранная страна, а вторая - выбранная лига.

как переделать скрипт, указанный выше, чтобы теперь создавался массив каждого `all_leagues1[0][1]`, `all_leagues1[0][2]`..?

Здесь я задавал похожий вопрос про скрипт: [Как сохранить результат выбранного селекта в массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792020/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5#792054) (первый ответ)

Comment: свойство `value` есть у любого селектора. Oбратите внимание на кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса - мощная вещь.

Comment: Буду знать, спасибо. Однако как обратится именно к 'value' второго селектора, который выбран после первого селектора я не могу понять